# how to programatically get system attribute label in magento

Tags: magento

I Have custom system attributes defined properly and all is working fine.
...

```
<export_group translate="label">
  <label>Products Import</label>
  <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
  <fields>
    <refresh_rate_input>
    <label>Refresh Rate: </label>
    <comment>Number of minutes..</comment>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
     .............          
    </refresh_rate_input>
   </fields>
 </export_group>
```

.....

I would like to be able to retrieve programmatically the label of the fields - in the above example "Refresh Rate: ", etc.

I want to use it during validation in my backend model and display its value via Mage::throwException(...... . "Refresh Rate: " . ....) etc..

Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, never tried.
Don't forget to change 3 first variables.

```
$section = "mysection";
$group = "mygroup";
$field = "myfield";

$label = Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config')->getSystemConfigNodeLabel($section, $group, $field);
echo $label; // Print result
```

Comment: getSystemConfigNodeLabel() generates event so you need to know who observes it, etc

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is what works for me:

```
$result = Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('system.xml')
          ->applyExtends()
          ->getNode('sections')
          ->xpath('//sections/' . $section . '/groups/' . $group . '/fields/' . $field);

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
  Mage::log((string)$node->label);
}
```